# How to make Expo.takeSnapshotAsync work on Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to figure out how to define the view argument in https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/take-snapshot-async.html

Function:

```
  screenShot = async () => {
      let result = await takeSnapshotAsync(this.pageView, {format: 'jpg', result: 'file', quality: 1.0});
          const file = {
            uri: result,
            name: this.state.shiftIDclean+"-clockIn.jpg",
            type: "image/jpeg"
          }
      }
```

View:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View ref={view => { this.pageView = view; }}>
        <Text>TEST CONTENT GOES HERE</Tex>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

This works fine on the iOS simulator but on Andriod, I get a red screen error: Trying to resolve view with tag 488 which doesn't exist.

I've tried to find a working example, but cannot.  I think the issue is I'm not defining which view I to screen shot correctly but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont know why but changing the View to this works:

```
  <View
    collapsable={false}
    ref={view => {
      this.pageView = view;
    }}>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a feeling that you singlehandedly just saved me a bunch of time! :-D How'd you originally figure this out?

Comment: Great, glad to give back.  So many people on stack overflow have saved me hours.

Comment: I think i figured this out by finding the original library that expo incorporated into their system and somewhere in there it had a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
  collapsable={false}
  ref={view => {
  this.pageView = view;
}}>
```

It's working properly because of `collapsable={false}`.
Set `collapsable`-property to `false` to disable this optimisation and ensure that this View exists in the native view hierarchy.